# .net control outputting span tags, remove?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net

Im working on a site built in .net - I have no idea how this works but I have the following...

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DP" runat="server" PagedControlID="LV" PageSize="5" QueryStringField="jobs">
    <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

The above outputs my html as follows

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_DP">
    <span>1</span>
    <a href="link">2</a>
    <a href="link">3</a>
    <a href="link">4</a>
</span>
```

Is there a way to output this as or is it not possible?...

```
<div>
    <span>
    <a>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to change the span to a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, `DataPager` doesn't support it *out of the box*. But you can extend `DataPager` class with overriding of the `TagKey` property:

```
public class YourDataPager : DataPager
{
   protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey 
   {
      get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div; }
   }
}
```

Now `YourDataPager` should outputs as a `<div>` instead of `<span>`.

Comment: +1 Didn't know that way, rather than the manual override - much neater - am off to change my code!

Answer (score 2):

In your server control you can override the `RenderBeginTag` method:

```
public override void RenderBeginTag(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.Write(String.Format("<div id=\"{0}\" class=\"{1}\">",
                               this.ClientID,this.CssClass));
}
```

Comment: And of course you'll need to override the `RenderEndTag` as well!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CssClass` to the `<asp:DataPager>`:

```
<asp:DataPager CssClass="myCSSClass" ID="DP" runat="server" PagedControlID="LV" PageSize="5" QueryStringField="jobs">
```

And it should output:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_DP" class="myCSSClass">
```

...and you can style accordingly from there.

Comment: Thanks @JamesDonnelly, is there a way to remove the parent span though and have it as a div? I dont really want to nest spans inside of spans?

Comment: That I'm not sure of, sorry. I've done very little work with ASP.NET before, and `CssClass` was the solution I used for styling purposes.